# Change chapter number font only

Tags: fonts, sectioning, chapters

I would like to redefine the `\thechapter` command in the aim to use the `eurb10` font only for the chapter number.

I try something like :

```
\newfont{\ChapNumbFont}{eurb10}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\ChapNumbFont{\@arabic\c@chapter}\normalfont}
```

But the chapter number font size is not correctly scaled in section, subsection...
It seems to use only the "normal" size and cannot "scaled" it.

What I'm doing wrong ?

PS : I'm using a book class strongly customized.

---

**Answer**

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer comment, I use this trick:

```
\renewcommand \thechapter {{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\selectfont\@arabic\c@chapter}}
```

There is a still a little font size difference.

Comment: While I can understand a different font in the chapter head, I don't think it's good to have the same font in the text, next to numbers in the normal font. In any case, `\newfont` is a deprecated command.

Comment: As I said before, the chapter number in the Euler font next to other digits in the normal text font has a rather disputable appearance. Euphemism for "is horrible". `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: I agree about the look. The look of the section and subsection numbers is simply odd - like font errors. I told Elendil not to redefine `\thechapter`:-(.

Comment: You are right that's not good. I was hoping a different layout but this is odd :-D. I will change it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to call the font in a scalable way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\selectfont abc 123
 \large abc 123}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that the "U" in `\fontencoding` means "unknown". So you can't rely on chars to be on standard positions. (But the numbers should be ok.)

You shouldn't put the font switching command in `\thechapter`: `\thechapter` is used in a lot of places. The font switch will e.g. end also in the headers, the toc and will be used when you reference a chapter as it will be stored with the label:

```
\newlabel{abc}{{\fontencoding  {U}\fontfamily  {eur}\fontseries  {b}\selectfont  1}{1}}
```

Comment: I used `\thechapter` in the aim to switch the font everywhere the chapter number is used (TOC, label...) to be consistent with the chapter header. So using `\renewcommand \thechapter {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\selectfont \@arabic\c@chapter\normalfont}` works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would remove the `\normalfont` command. Better add additional braces to keep the font switch local.